# CSS3 Gradients and Transparency Combined?

Tags: css, gradient

I need to use cool gradients in my current HTML5 mobile app, and was wondering how I can use CSS3 gradients to achieve something like http://goo.gl/op63lu

I made a little fiddle to try my hands (http://jsfiddle.net/YRxsK/) but it did not come close to the amazing gradients from the links above, and this is where I need help!

```
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, right top, color-stop(0%,#323232), color-stop(100%,#C62F35));
```

I want to use these colours
a deep red: #C62F35
a light red: #94b435
a very light red: #FFF1E0
a cool green: #fd4246
and any other complementing colors

Answer (score 0):

It's not really an answer but take a look at http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ A very good tool for generating all sorts of gradients.

For instance to get one more similar to your link pick radial from the drop down in the top right.